# Connect wordpress with mysql using md5 password

Tags: wordpress

I'm working with a remote site with a client.
My issue is: I'm trying to don't share my mysql password.
Exist a way to connect mysql using an encrypted password (like md5)?

Comment: Just create a mysql user to your client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress can't use encrypted passwords in wp-config.php. In PHPMyAdmin or Adminer, simply setup a different MySQL user and assign it to the database. When you're done with the client, delete the user.